# Swift 2: Missing argument for parameter 'time' in call

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and trying to create and use a class, but I'm getting an error:  "Missing argument for parameter 'time' in call"
Can someone point me in the right direction?  I've looked at a few samples on the Apple website, but no luck.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
Bryan

Here's my class:

```
class CurrentSevereReportModel {
var time: NSDate?
var magnitude: String?
var location: String?
var county: String?
var remarks: String?
var lat: NSNumber?
var lon: NSNumber?
var type: NSNumber?
var reportid: NSNumber?

init(time: NSDate, magnitude: String, location: String, county: String, remarks: String, lat: NSNumber, lon: NSNumber, type: NSNumber, reportid: NSNumber) {
    self.time = time
    self.magnitude = magnitude
    self.location  = location
    self.county = county
    self.remarks = remarks
    self.lat = lat
    self.lon = lon
    self.type = type
    self.reportid = reportid
}
```

}

Here's how I'm trying to use it and getting the error:  "Missing argument for parameter 'time' in call"

```
var records: [CurrentSevereReportModel]

func buildRecord(data : [String : String], type : Int, index:Int)
{
    let record = CurrentSevereReportModel() // <-- error here

    var timeDate = data[reportHeaders[0]]!

    let length = timeDate.characters.count
    if (length > 4)
    {
        let index1 = timeDate.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)

        timeDate = timeDate.substringFromIndex(index1)
    }else if (length < 4)
    {
        let restCount = 4 - length
        var index: Int = 0
        for index = 0; index < restCount; index++
        {
            timeDate = "0" + timeDate
        }
    }

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyMMddHHmm"

    record.time = dateFormatter.dateFromString(timeDate)

    record.type = type
    record.magnitude = data[reportHeaders[1]]!
    record.location = data[reportHeaders[2]]!
    record.county = data[reportHeaders[3]]!
    record.remarks = data[reportHeaders[4]]!
    record.lat = Double(data[reportHeaders[5]]!)
    record.lon = Double(data[reportHeaders[6]]!)
    record.comments = data[reportHeaders[7]]!
    record.reportid = index
    print(record.reportid)
    records.append(record)
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're running init without any values passed in. When you set self.time=time there is no value for that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't think that doing initialization in this way is a good idea.
Couple of arguments:

1. You're creating object at start with no arguments, and you're not using it anywhere. So why create it so early?
2. You're making variables Optionals. It means that they can be nil in this example - is this really what you mean? Based on what I see here, you should make them non-optional variables and use initializer you wrote in class. It's really safer, and makes in a lot of easier to use class(because you're sure that variables exists and are non-nil.

If you really need this kind of behavior(i strongly advise against in), and you're looking for getting rid of error, just create empty initializer:
`init() {}`

It'll do the work.

Comment: thank you for your explanation.  That does make since to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Your initializer is defined:

```
init(time: NSDate, magnitude: String, location: String, county: String,  
   remarks: String, lat: NSNumber, lon: NSNumber, type: NSNumber, 
   reportid: NSNumber) {
```

That means you must *call* it the way you *defined* it:

```
let record = CurrentSevereReportModel(time: someDate, magnitude: someString,
   // ... and so on ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Based on what kacprh mentioned above and your example, I'm now on the right track.

Comment: Glad to help! I have written a book on Swift and much of it is available for free online, so you might want to read that. http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/